# Why quarkus CLI uses maven?

Tags: quarkus

This is just a general curiosity question:

I was just playing with Quarkus after a while, and I've noticed that after creating a project - using the CLI -  and launching `quarkus dev` the shipped build system by default uses a maven wrapper - would be interested to know on the technical motivations to use it rather than, for example others like Gradle.

I've browsed for any related blog/post on couldn't find any, would be great to get some insights from the community.

Comment: Maven is not the one and only build tool which is supported by Quarkus. It's just the default. Probably it's just a historical thing. You can also use [Gradle, even with Kotlin dsl](https://quarkus.io/guides/gradle-tooling), it's your choice. It isn't about which is better or worse, not at all. Everything else is opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

Quarkus CLI doesn't use only maven, it uses Gradle or JBang.

You can see in [documentaiton](https://quarkus.io/guides/cli-tooling) that there is a note on every execution of the quarkus-cli

```
Output will vary depending on the build tool your project is using (Maven, Gradle, or JBang).
```

The build tool depends on what you choose when you create the project, for example, if you created the project in [code.quarkus.io](https://code.quarkus.io/) you can choose Build Tool Gradle.

However, I don't see how to create a Gradle project with

```
quarkus create app
```